# How do I prepare store-bought plants for use in a terrarium?

Tags: safety, terrariums, plants, amphibians

I've recently adopted a pair of American tree frogs, and have set up a terrarium for them.

I purchased some plants for the terrarium from a local garden center, and while the species of plants are considered safe, I'm concerned that the potential use of fertilizers (and maybe even pesticides) on the plants while they were at the garden center might be harmful.

What can I do to make sure that the plants are safe for the tree frogs, before adding them to their terrarium?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to cut back the oldest leaves if it is possible. This depends on the type of plant you have.

If this is impossible to do, you have to rinse it in cold water and fully submerge the plant for about 15 minutes.

You will need to remove the soil from the roots of your plant and replace it with a 50/50 mix of sand and unfertilized soil.

A small amount of fertilizer in the soil will probably not be harmful to your frog. I think pesticides in the food pose a larger risk to your frog.